# PHP Image Upload

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to upload an image to a folder and save the path in a table. I tried to upload a jpg image but it's displaying the errors:

> The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.

and

> Undefined index: userfile in C:\wamp\www\web\db_add_page.php on line 21.

This is my code:

**add_page.php**

```
<form action="db_sql/db_add_page.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" size="100" name="tittle" required />
    <input type="file" name="userfile"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**db_add_page.php**

```
$tittle = $_POST['tittle'];
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif');
$max_filesize = 10485760;
$upload_path = 'uploads/';

$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

if (!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
  die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

if (filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
  die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

if (!is_writable($upload_path))
  die('You cannot upload to the specified directory');

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
{
    $acc_status = "INSERT INTO add_services (aid,tittle,name)
    VALUES(NULL,'".$tittle."','".$filename."')";
    db::getInstance()->exec($acc_status);
}
```

Comment: it can be capital (.JPG, .JPEG, .PNG, .GIF).. mostly camera-generated images are doing this.

Comment: also add this attribute to the form tag <form action="db_sql/db_add_page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: same error "The file you attempted to upload is not allowed."

Comment: there's a gazillion dupes of this question... srsly

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing attribute in the <form> tag. You need to set *envtype* to get files.
Try this:

```
<form action="db_sql/db_add_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

finaly i found my error

```
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);
```

should be

```
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

and

```
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif');
```

should be

```
$allowed_filetypes = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');
```

thanks for your support.